# Angular KendoGrid not passing value to subgrid through @Input variable

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am having trouble passing a value to my subgrid. Everything else works, but my input variable always comes up undefined. Has anyone else had this issue? I've looked and looked for an answer, but no dice. Here's my main grid declaration:

```
  selector: 'app-invoice-matching-grid',
  templateUrl: './invoice-matching-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./invoice-matching-grid.component.css'],
  template: `
        <kendo-grid 
          [data]="gridView" 
          [height]="600"

        (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
          >
          <kendo-grid-column >
          </kendo-grid-column>
          <div *kendoGridDetailTemplate="let dataItem">
              <app-invoice-line-items [category]="96"></app-invoice-line-items>
          </div>
        </kendo-grid>
    `
})
```

And here is my subgrid:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { GridDataResult, GridComponent, PageChangeEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import {Invoice, InvoiceLineItem} from 'src/app/invoice-matching-grid/invoice-matching-grid.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-invoice-line-items',
  templateUrl: './invoice-line-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./invoice-line-items.component.css'],
  template: `
      <kendo-grid
          [data]="invoices"
          [pageSize]="5"
          [skip]="skip"
          [pageable]="true"
          scrollable="none"
          (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"

          [navigable]="true"
          kendoGridFocusable
        >

        <kendo-grid-column>
          </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class InvoiceLineItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public category: string;

  public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
  public skip = 0;

  public invoices: Invoice[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    console.log(this.category);
   }

  public ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try logging it on `ngAfterViewInit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `@Input` is not available in the constructor, you have to use the [`ngOnInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) hook

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   console.log(this.category);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! First Angular project, obviously still working out the kinks :)